# Regex Conditional Lookahead JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I just used [regex101](https://regex101.com), to create the following regex.

```
([^,]*?)=(.*?)(?(?=, )(?:, )|(?:$))(?(?=[^,]*?=)(?:(?=[^,]*?=))|(?:$))
```

It seems to work perfectly for my use case of getting keys and values that are comma separated while still preserving commas in the values.

Problem is, I want to use this Regex in Node.js (JavaScript), but while writing this entire Regex in regex101, I had it set to PCRE (PHP).

It looks like JavaScript doesn't support Conditional Lookaheads (`(?(?=...)()|()`).

Is there a way to get this working in JavaScript?

---

**Examples:**

2 matches

group 1: `id`, group 2: `1`

group 1: `name`, group 2: `bob`

```
id=1, name=bob
```

---

3 matches

group 1: `id`, group 2: `2`

group 1: `type`, group 2: `store`

group 1: `description`, group 2: `Hardwood Store`

```
id=2, type=store, description=Hardwood Store
```

---

4 matches

group 1: `id`, group 2: `4`

group 1: `type`, group 2: `road`

group 1: `name`, group 2: `The longest road name, in the entire world, and universe, forever`

group 1: `built`, group 2: `20190714`

```
id=4, type=road, name=The longest road name, in the entire world, and universe, forever, built=20190714
```

---

3 matches

group 1: `id`, group 2: `3`

group 1: `type`, group 2: `building`

group 1: `builder`, group 2: `Random Name, and Other Person, with help from Final Person`

```
id=3, type=building, builder=Random Name, and Other Person, with help from Final Person
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
/([^,=\s][^,=]*)=(.*?)(?=(?:,\s*)?[^,=]*=|$)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5fFQV5/2).

**Details**

- `([^,=\s][^,=]*)` - Group 1:

  - `[^,=\s]`  - a char other than `,`, `=` and whitespace
  - `[^,=]*` - zero or more chars other than `,` and `=`
- `=` - a `=` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=(?:,\s*)?[^,=]*=|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires an optional sequence of `,` and 0+ whitespaces and then 0+ chars other than `,` and `=` and then a `=` or end of string immediately to the right of the current location

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['id=1, name=bob','id=2, type=store, description=Hardwood Store', 'id=4, type=road, name=The longest road name, in the entire world, and universe, forever, built=20190714','id=3, type=building, builder=Random Name, and Other Person, with help from Final Person']
var rx = /([^,=\s][^,=]*)=(.*?)(?=(?:,\s*)?[^,=]*=|$)/g;
for (var s of strs) {
   console.log("STRING:", s);
   var m;
   while (m=rx.exec(s)) {
     console.log(m[1], m[2])
   }
}
```

Comment: This works really well! Thanks for the detailed explanation. Only problem, is I realized that some of the values have = signs in them as well. So now I have to figure out a way to ensure there is a comma before the =, or else it's part of the value. For example `id=1, url=https://test.com/hello/world?name=bob, random=5`. 3 matches here. `id` & `1`, `url` & `https://test.com/hello/world?name=bob`, `random` & `5`.

Comment: @CharlieFish I thought the comma and spaces are optional. If not use https://regex101.com/r/5fFQV5/3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, these expressions would be somewhat close to what you might want to design:

```
([^=\n\r]*)=\s*([^=\n\r]*)\s*(?:,|$)
```

or

```
\s*([^=\n\r]*)=\s*([^=\n\r]*)\s*(?:,|$)
```

not sure though.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/QPD1RZ/1/)

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/1wxJLN/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

```js
const regex = /\s*([^=\n\r]*)=\s*([^=\n\r]*)\s*(?:,|$)/gm;
const str = `id=3, type=building, builder=Random Name, and Other Person, with help from Final Person

id=4, type=road, name=The longest road name, in the entire world, and universe, forever, built=20190714

id=2, type=store, description=Hardwood Store
id=1, name=bob

`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it

`\s*([^,=]*?)\s*=\s*((?:(?![^,=]*=)[\S\s])*)(?=[=,]|$)`

https://regex101.com/r/J6SSGr/1

Readable version

```
 \s* 
 ( [^,=]*? )                   # (1), Key
 \s* = \s*                     #       =
 (                             # (2 start), Value
      (?:
           (?! [^,=]* = )
           [\S\s] 
      )*
 )                             # (2 end)
 (?= [=,] | $ )
```

---

***Ultimate PCRE version***

`\s*([^,=]*?)\s*=\s*((?:(?!\s*[^,=]*=)[\S\s])*(?<![,\s]))\s*(?=[=,\s]|$)`

https://regex101.com/r/slfMR1/1

```
 \s*                           # Wsp trim
 ( [^,=]*? )                   # (1), Key
 \s* = \s*                     # Wsp trim =  Wsp trim
 (                             # (2 start), Value
      (?:
           (?! \s* [^,=]* = )
           [\S\s] 
      )*
      (?<! [,\s] )                  # Wsp trim
 )                             # (2 end)
 \s*                           # Wsp trim
 (?= [=,\s] | $ )              # Field seperator
```